# Project template for jQuery/Ajax in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webstorm

I'm getting started with Ajax (jQuery) using WebStorm and not sure what project template to use for it.

I've added the jQuery plugin in WebStorm, but that doesn't give me additional project templates to choose from. I was hoping for some equivalent of say a new Angular JS project (which gives you a stub of what a typical project may look like in terms of structure), as I've never used jQuery/Ajax.

Or is that somewhat irrelevant, there isn't a lot more to it than just starting an empty project, adding an html & a .js file and start from there?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "jQuery/ Ajax" template. jQuery uses ajax to connect to a controller or external source, but that's just a function call. And your jQuery is just standard js code with calls to the jQuery library. If you want a stub, it's literally a blank html file with a <script> pointing at jQuery library file.

Comment: Oh okay - so I guess just the HTML5 boilerplate would do (or empty project as you say). Seems silly but I've come across lots to tut/vids about ajax/jquery but not much about project setup.

Comment: That because there is no project setup. jQuery is just a library for standard JS. As long as you can execute JS, and have included the jQuery library, it will work. As far as ajax, if you use `$.ajax({})`, that's just a function call.